# Automatic generation of translation file for Resource.resx is not working

Tags: c#, localization, csproj, resource-files, asp.net-core-localization

I need to generate another language translation file automatically based on my `Resources.resx` file.

I already have the following lines present in my **.csproj** project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
        <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.de.resx">
        <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

With the above settings in place, the expected file `Resources.de.resx` neither gets generated automatically nor does it gets updated automatically when I add a new key to the `Resources.resx` file.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [XLocalizer](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/XLocalizer/v1.0/index.md), it can generate resource files and translations automatically, and it supports XML, DB, RESX or any custom resource type to store localization texts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

```
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.de.resx">
        <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
```

to also include a generator like so

```
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.de.resx">
        <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
```

At least this is how it looks in my projects, I usually just add the resource files through the solution explorer

**EDIT:**

Sorry I should have read your `.csproj` more carefully, your approach is different from what I'm familiar with.

In fact, I've changed the project files of one of my project to mirror yours and it generates both files correctly.

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Update="Resources\EntityLocalizations.Designer.cs">
            <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
            <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
            <DependentUpon>EntityLocalizations.resx</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\EntityLocalizations.de.resx">       
            <DependentUpon>EntityLocalizations.resx</DependentUpon>
        </EmbeddedResource>
        <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\EntityLocalizations.resx">
            <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>           
            <LastGenOutput>EntityLocalizations.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
            <SubType>Designer</SubType>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
```

[image: result]

So it *should* work

Comment: Tried, still same issue.